# Can't apply styles to React using loaders

Tags: css, reactjs, webpack

In my webpack.config.js, I added "style-loader" and "css-loader" as recommended.
I also imported styles from "./style.css"(import styles from "./style.css") in my root component. But it doesn't apply styles to my app. What am I doing wrong? What am I missing?
I've got "Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory'"

```
  ...
 output: {
   path: __dirname + './static',
   filename: 'app.bundle.js'
 }, 
 {
   test:/\.css$/,
   use: [
      "style-loader",
      "css-loader",
     ]
 }
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your `output.path` is wrong. Works for me like this.

EDIT: also, the loaders go inside modules.rules

```
const path = require('path');
.
.
.    

output: {
   path: path.join(__dirname, 'static/')
   filename: 'app.bundle.js'
 },
 module: {
  rules:[
 {
   test:/\.css$/,
   use: [
      "style-loader",
      "css-loader",
     ]
 }
]}
```

Comment: I've got another "Error: Element from loaders list should have one of the fields 'loader' or 'loaders". Just can't make it work .

Answer (score 0):

You should change to `loader` something like this

```
module: {
        rules: [{
                test: /\.scss$/,
                use: [
                    'style-loader',
                    MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                    {
                        loader: "css-loader",
                        options: {
                            minimize: true,
                            sourceMap: true
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        loader: "sass-loader"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: ["babel-loader", "eslint-loader"]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$/i,
                loader: "file-loader"
            },
            {
                test: /\.(woff|ttf|otf|eot|woff2|svg)$/i,
                loader: "file-loader"
            }
        ]
    }
```